# Mac App Store stuck on Sign In

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, mac-appstore

I recently installed a fresh (erased my HD) install of OS X El Capitan 10.11.3

During my first log in I skipped sign in to my apple id

Now when I open my Mac App Store and try to Sign In, it gets stuck after I press Sign In button

I am using proxy authentication from my university

[image]

Comment: Let me suppose that you have entered your Apple ID and just erased it on screenshot for the security reasons, right? :) Next, I would suggest to wait some time. This happens and it might take about +/- 5 minutes to wait. After that first long one, you'll be able to login normally, i.e. not waiting this long.

Comment: Yeah, I erased my userid from screenshot. I had to force restart (pressing power button) since app store was not quitting. I also tried logging to iCloud account from System Preference which has same id as in app store.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, after a restart!